# salesforce - how to make API_Session_ID available to javascript

Tags: salesforce

I have a javascript app running in a home page component. It calls into a web service, which in turn calls the salesforce API. I would like to use the API_Session_ID variable to save re-logging in. How do I expose this to the javascript running in my home page component? Ideally I would like to use apex to render a small piece of script, initialising a javascript variable with the API_Session_ID variable, onto all pages, but I can't see how to do this.

Note - I can't use VF as the app is running in a home page component. The normal solution for that (run as VF in an iframe) is not available to me as I need to access the javascript objects in the main page, which I can't do from an iframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I figured this out. There's a value 'sid' in the session cookie, and that's what one needs with a bit of tweaking. Easy when you know how! Here's the link:

http://forums.sforce.com/t5/forums/forumtopicprintpage/board-id/general_development/message-id/7209/print-single-message/false/page/1

It's a bit out of date. I pass the cookie sid value, and window.location.host to my php web service. The php to make these values work is:

```
$sidparts = explode("!", $feed->sid['value']);
$location = "https://".parse_url($feed->server['value'],
    PHP_URL_HOST)."/services/Soap/u/20.0/".$sidparts[0];
$sessionId = "{$feed->sid['value']}";
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to do the same thing a few times as well. Unfortunately, I haven't had success without VisualForce.

I did find a discussion thread on the topic a few days ago, though.
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/AJAX-Toolkit-S-Controls/Detect-current-user-with-AJAX-toolkit/m-p/277241#M8485

Also, it sounds like you know this, but to get the Session ID using VisualForce:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Matthew - thanks for the response. I have figured it out actually and this might be useful to you: http://forums.sforce.com/t5/forums/forumtopicprintpage/board-id/general_development/message-id/7209/print-single-message/false/page/1 - I will answer my own question more completely as soon as SA allows me to ...

Comment: Nice find! Grabbing the cookie is a creative solution.

Comment: The session id in the sid cookie on the force.com domain used by VisualForce pages isn't valid for use with the API, so you have to use {!GETSESSIONID()}.  I was trying to use it with the ajax library from within a user script: http://bit.ly/POfbrW